# Child Tasks Vs WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I am not sure what is the benefit of creating child tasks when I can have the parent task wait for all the tasks it created. I run the following code and it produced the same result in both cases.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunWithChildren();
    RunWithWait();
}


private static void RunWithChildren()
{
    Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var results = new Int32[3];
        new Task(r => results[0] = 0, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
        new Task(r => results[1] = 1, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
        new Task(r => results[2] = 2, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
        return results;
    });

    var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
    {
        foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    });

    finalTask.Wait();
}


private static void RunWithWait()
{
    Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var results = new Int32[3];
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => results[0] = 0);
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => results[1] = 1);
        Task t3 = Task.Run(() => results[2] = 2);

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
        return results;
    });

    var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(parentTask =>
    {
        foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    });

    finalTask.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AttachedToParent` offers you a different way to structure your code. If child `Task`s can start in various places in the code of the parent `Task`, using `AttachedToParent` means you don't have to worry about collecting all the child `Task`s into a collection.

In practice, I think that `Task.WaitAll()` is clearer and collecting the `Task` is not actually a problem, so I would almost never use `AttachedToParent`.